# Why linkaxis doesn't work if I try to link date time and latitudes in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, axis-labels

I have two subplot, first one has UTCTime on x-Axis and second has Latitudes degrees on x-Axis. I need to link x-axis to "align" UTCTime with latitude degree.

For example I have `UTCTime(2) = 2018-08-12...` and `Latitudes(2) = -50`.

I tried with `linkaxis(ax1, ax2, 'x')` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about what you're asking... you want to link two different variable types (datetime and double). Yes, they have a real-world relationship in the use-case you've got, but MATLAB has no "sense" of how to link different data types.

Convert your datetime data to datenum (i.e. double) and it should work.